# Java Spring Boot Configurations & Components

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I'm trying to use a component to load up my configuration yml file.

However, it throws a Null Pointer exception and System.out shows 'null' for application.

However, when the same pattern is used to code up a @RestController, everything works fine. Why is @component not seeing my configurations??

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myconf")
public class AppConfigJSON {

    private String application;
    private final String applicationConfigJSON;
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private final ReadContext acRcJson;

public AppConfigJSON(){
        String json = "";
        try {
            System.out.println("Application: " + this.application);
            json = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myconfs/"+this.application+".json"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error reading JSON or app YML {}", e.getStackTrace());            
        }
        this.applicationConfigJSON = json;
        this.acRcJson = JsonPath.parse(this.getApplicationConfigJSON());
    }


// These functions below set by configuration
public String getApplication()
{
    return application;
}

public void setApplication(String application)
{
    this.application = application;
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure the AppConfigJSON class package is under the basePackageScan defined in your app.

Comment: How do I do that? It's in the same package. the same level as my @SpringBootApplication.

Comment: P.s. It detects it in the same level RestController... but NOT in Component class that I made. I made a test_this_class, and even that didn't work. Both says "application: null"

Comment: Also the NullPointerException goes AWAY if you remove the "parse" (because I can't parse a "null application variable". But why won't configuration yml get put inside my component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor the application variable hasn't been initialized yet, in other words, Spring needs an instance first so it can apply it's magic. You need to move your constructor logic to a method annotated with `@PostContruct` so the application variable is set with the property value at that point.

Comment: This was just what I discovered 1 minute ago haha, but I didn't check this for over an hour. You are right. @PostConstruct void init() throws IOException { }